# Measure agreement among experts in multi-label classification task

Tags: classification, metric, multilabel

I was wondering whether there is a metric that can be used in order to compute the agreement, and therefore something like an upper bound for classifiers, among expert-labelled data.

Assume there is a multi-label problem where $N$ documents have to be tagged using tags from a set of tags (e.g. *car*, *house*, *animal*) and three experts.

```
           Document 1    Document 2       Document 3     Document 4
Expert 1:  [car, house]  [animal]         [car, animal]  []
Expert 2:  [car]         [animal]         [car, animal]  []
Expert 3:  [car, house]  [animal, house]  [car, animal]  [animal]
```

Are there ways to compute an "agreement score" and ultimately determine an upper bound for an artificial classifier?

Comment: have you considered inter rater reliability statistics?

Comment: Well, I've been reading about the [kappa](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.cohen_kappa_score.html) score but this seems to be limited to just two "experts" and does not seem to work for multi-label problems. I could work around that and just apply it for each class separately but I it seems I can only compare two outcomes at once.

Comment: Fleis's Kappa solves the issue regarding the number of experts.

Comment: @DimitriosZacharatos Yes indeed, I just found [this paper](https://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/pdf/10.1162/coli.07-034-R2) which appears to give a very nice overview of different methods and metrics. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Cohen's Kappa, treating each category as an independent question (the fact that it's multi-class multi-label makes me think you have to compute agreement for each). Then when aggregating it, I'd probably use a linear average across all categories.